# Tool to convert XIB to XAML

Tags: maui

I have a very large iOS app that I want to move over to .NET MAUI. All of the UI views are in xib format and obviously, they can't just be used within MAUI so need covnerting to XAML.

Is there an automated way or a tool that will take the xib files and output to XAML (not worried if it's not propertly MAUI compliant, I can fix that up)? I've looked online and other than something I started ages ago (which wasn't very good), can't find anything that will do the conversion.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: The simple and direct answer for this is NO